# Changing a "target=_" in a hardcoded href link

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

We have a WordPress site that uses the 3DCart Widget - it dynamically populates the products section of the page. See this page for an example

http://www.slipcovermall.com/chairs/wing-chair/

The issue is, the plugin hardcodes "target="_new" in each product link, so when you click on "add to cart" you are taken to a new browser window. Is there a JavaScript way in the page header to change any target called to self, or remove the target= altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery (which was included on that page, so I assume it's ok):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a[target='_new']").removeAttr("target");
});
```

If jQuery is not available, use

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[_target='new']")
```

iterate over all elements and invoke `removeAttribute("target")`:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[target='_new']");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].removeAttribute("target");
}
```

Comment: It's possible I'm overlooking something obvious, but what's with the `_` before `target`?

Comment: @thinklinux Neither does JavaScript as a whole, yet we still use it. It's called progress :p

Comment: @Kolink I agree!! but when you don't know the visitors of the site you have to give solution that works on all platforms

Comment: @user2132913 did you try it before or after alexn fixed the typos? ;)

Comment: The script needs to execute after the page is done loading, otherwise it'll execute before there are any `a` elements to select and check for `target` in the first place.

Comment: @user2132913 The problem is that the DOM tree is not ready when that function is invoked. Wrap it in $(document).ready() or window.onload.

Comment: What would be the way to tie it in with window.onload? (I am a designer, so thanks for the help)

Comment: @alexn, may be you should edit your answer with the $(document).ready update

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since this is wordpress, i suggest you wrap the code in a jQuery function: 
Note - Most wordpress themes use jQuery, you just need to call it properly...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function ($) { 
    $('a').removeAttr('target');

    OR

    $('a').attr('target','_self');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery on the site so you can do that:

`$("a").removeAttr("target")`

Comment: can you tell us what are you doing exactly? : )